# Type of singularity of $h(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(4z-\pi)}$, $z=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> Let $$h(z)=\frac{1}{\sin(4z-\pi)}$$ What kind of singularity does
>   function $h(z)$ at the point $z=\frac{\pi}{4}$?

I know from theory that the point is essential singularity if and only if $\lim_{z \to z_0}h(z)$ does not exist OR Laurent series $a_{-m} \ne 0 $ $\forall m\in\Bbb{N}$.

First of all, I don't know, how to calculate the limit by myself without using wolfram alpha and to see that the limit does not exit so $z=\frac{\pi}{4}$ is essential singularity. On the other hand, wolfram alpha says that Laurent series of function h(z) has $a_{-1}$ and that contradicts $a_{-m} \ne 0 $ $\forall m\in\Bbb{N}$.

So, my question is: how to solve this problem and why two different methods give me different answers? Or maybe this is not even essential singularity?

Comment: it’s a simple pole.

Comment: @Szeto any 'more' explanations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theoretical part is not correct. The point $\frac\pi4$ would be an essential singularity if and only if $a_m\neq0$ for infinitely many $n$'s, not for *all* of them.

Anyway, $\lim_{z\to\frac\pi4}\frac{z-\frac\pi4}{\sin(4z-\pi)}=\frac14$ and therefore your function has a pole of order $1$ at $\frac\pi4$.

Comment: I see. Thank you! Could you please tell me how would you solve this problem:
does the function $h(z)$ hold Cauchy-Riemann equations at the point $z=-\frac{\pi}{3}$? Can I just check if $h(z)$ is continuous at this point?

Comment: That's another question. Please post it as such, And if my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.